# JQuery Button click not working along with overflow-y on Android 4.2.2

Tags: jquery, cordova, buttonclick

We are using a jQuery Mobile popup in a Cordova app. The button click event is not firing when we enable scrolling (using `overflow-y`). This issue is happening only on Android 4.2.2, whereas it seems to be working fine on other versions.
We have tried multiple options but could not fix this!

```
<div data-role="popup" id="main" style:'height: 60%;'> 
    <div id="header"></div> 
    <div id="content" style='height: 90%; overflow-y: scroll'></div> 
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var data = ""; 
    data += "" ;

    //some images 
    data += "<div id='main_buttons'><div style='margin-left:10%;margin-right:10%;font-size:40px'>some text here</div>"; 
    data += "<table style='margin-left:10%;' width='82%'><tr width='82%'><td align='right'><button type='submit' id='btn1' >Adjust button</button></td>"; 
    data += "</tr></table></div>";     

    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data;

    //click event 
    $(document).on("click", "#btn1", function(e){ 
        alert("button clicked"); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? How are the elements nested?

Comment: In Html :
<div data-role="popup" id="main" style:'height:60%;'>
 <div id="header"></div>
 <div id="content" style='height:90%;overflow-y:scroll'>  </div>
</div>

Comment: In script:
$(document).ready(function(){
 var data = "";
 data += "" ;//some images
 data += "<div id='main_buttons'><div style='margin-left:10%;margin-right:10%;font-size:40px'>some text here</div>";
 data += "<table style='margin-left:10%;' width='82%'><tr width='82%'><td align='right'><button type='submit'  id='btn1' >Adjust button</button></td>";
 data += "</tr></table></div>";
 document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data;
 
 //click event
 $(document).on("click","#btn1",function(e){
  alert("button clicked");
 });
});

Comment: Hi... you are new to this site, so I'll be kind: Please edit your original post with the code. format it beautifully, with the buttons above the textarea... then delete your comments here... comment-section is not for code, especially not, if it belongs to the original post..